# Check for element with given class, case not found, add class to first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, each

How do you do that:

**On a set of elements, check if there's any with a given class.
Case not found, add the class to the first element of the set.**

I came up with the code below.

It works well, but, is there a simpler/cleaner/cleverer way to do it?

```
var noActiveElement = true;

$('.list-group-item').each(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
         noActiveElement = false;
         return false;
     }                    
 });

  if (noActiveElement)
     $('.list-group-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

testing `length` of elements found by selector is about the simplest way

```
if( !$('.list-group-item.active').length ){
  $('.list-group-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
}
```

When you use `$(selector)` an array of elements matching the selector is created. If none found the length of array is zero

Comment: I was also missing `.length`. Here's a demo. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/neqtr3jd/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('.list-group-item.active').length) {
  $('.list-group-item').eq(0).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: i've got the same answer already (except for the missing quotation mark) ;)